# Issue with Google Developer's Service Account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I am trying to create Google Service Account to add Google based auth for my Jenkins server. When i do it i get the success message

> Service account created The service account "test" was given editor
>   permission for the project.
>
> The account's public/private key pair Jenkins-abec3f911496.json has
>   been saved on your computer. This is the only copy of the key, so
>   store it securely.

However i can not find the public/private key pair. I have searched the whole machine `( cd / ; find . -name "*.json" )`

I am on a MAC Notebook using Safari as my browser. Not sure if its related to any of that. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with downloading the file on Safari. Try creating a new key on Firefox or Chrome. It should start downloading immediately once that dialog appears.

**Update:** It is now fixed for Safari!

Comment: Sorry about not updating my question earlier. It indeed was file download issue in Safari and it didn't even prompt me that its blocking a download :-). I feel so dumb. Thanks for your response

Comment: I was using Safari before and it was so frustrating! Using chrome worked for me! Thanks!